# How to compute based on condition in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.323</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.324</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.325</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.326</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.327</ip_address>
</Data>
```

I am trying to achieve below output. I think, logic will be to have two variable, and for each occurence, substring the last part and assign min and max and at last concat first 3 part+(dot)+min+(-)+max. Any suggestion, how to write xsl for it?

```
<ipAdress>192.100.200.323-327</ipAdress>
```

Comment: Well, XSLT/XPath 2.0 and later has a `tokenize` function and `min` and `max` functions so it should be straight-forward. What happens if there are `ip_address` elements that differ in the first three bytes of the address?

Comment: First three bytes will be always same.

Comment: Is it possible to have an ip missing from the range? Like in your example, would it be possible for .326 to be missing? If so, would the output need to be different?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that is based on the following assumptions:

- You can use XSLT 2.0
- The answer to my questions in the comments are all "yes".

I'm also making an assumption on what the output should look like if an ip in the range is missing. This should at least be a start.

**XML Input**

```
<Data>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.323</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.324</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.325</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.326</ip_address>
    <ip_address action="del">192.100.200.327</ip_address>
</Data>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ip_address" 
        group-by="replace(normalize-space(),'\d+$','')">
        <xsl:variable name="base" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="no-base">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <ip>
                <xsl:value-of 
                  select="replace(normalize-space(),current-grouping-key(),'')"/>
              </ip>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$no-base/ip"
          group-starting-with="ip[preceding-sibling::ip[1] + 1 != .]">
          <ip_address>
            <xsl:value-of
              select="if (current-group()[1]=current-group()[last()]) then 
              concat($base,current-group()[1]) else 
              concat($base,current-group()[1],'-',current-group()[last()])"
            />
          </ip_address>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Data>
   <ip_address>192.100.200.323-327</ip_address>
</Data>
```

If:

```
<ip_address action="del">192.100.200.326</ip_address>
```

is removed from the input, the output is:

```
<Data>
   <ip_address>192.100.200.323-325</ip_address>
   <ip_address>192.100.200.327</ip_address>
</Data>
```

Comment: I am looking, what you have mentioned in output. Thank You! is there any way to implement it using 1.0?